# Using "their" or "its" when referring to an inanimate object

Tags: sentence-construction, determiners

I'm a bit confused on the usage of "their" and "its". For example, if I had the following phrase:

> Each of these programs had ______ code reviewed by an expert.

Will I use "their code" or "its code"?

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that, when talking about things, you use **its** for singular and **their** for plural. There is one exception relating to **their**, for which the [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/their?q=their) defines two usages:

> 1. of or belonging to people, animals or **things** that have already been mentioned or are easily identified
> 2. used instead of his or her to refer to a **person** whose sex is not mentioned or not known

As 米凯乐 stated, when you use **each**, you must use a singular, and the first usage is only valid for **plural** things. The second usage is valid for singular, but only for a **person**, not for things. You therefore cannot use **their** in this sentence, because it is a thing and must be singuar: you should use **its**.

Answer (score 1):

@米凯乐 is correct about how "each" and "none" affect number of conjugation, but not about making a sentence with "their".

The idea is that "its" or "it" refers to something in general or to some non-person, inanimate thing while "their" or "they" refers to people and even pets. "Their" and "they" can be used in the third-person singular. When used (instead of her or his) to refer to a person, "their" simply includes no information as to **their** gender:

> Each of these **programmers** had **their** code reviewed by an expert.
>
> Of these, each **programmer** had **their** code reviewed by an expert.
>
> Here are the **programmers**. **They** each had **their** code reviewed by an expert.
>
> Here is a **programmer**. **They** had **their** code reviewed by an expert.

For your original example using "program" as the subject, I would use "its" since programs are not people:

> Each of these **programs** had **its** code reviewed by an expert.

Answer (score 0):

"Their" can be a gender-neutral pronoun when discussing people. Each of these people had their car stolen. Everything else would be 'its'. Some people allow pet animals; other don't.